# Expect in bash script?

Tags: bash, shell-script, terminal, expect

Is there a way to use `expect` command directly in a `bash script` for which the automation is to be done, instead of writing a `expect script` and use `spawn` command to trigger the `bash script` from `expect script`?

Like altogether in one script?

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. [How do I ask a good question?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Is it okay now ?

Comment: For me the `bash via expect` is what is working (running the bash script with `spawn`). When I use expect in bash it does not work, Do we need to include something(like `spawn`  for bash) to make it work?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. Yes you can control a shell script with expect. Yes you can embed expect code in a shell script. Are you trying to control the shell script that embeds expect code with that same expect code?

Comment: Like, if a shell script need to be automated then two scripts are created - one shell and another for expect ( and the shell script is `spawned` from expect script). My question is - Is there a way to do it in a single script?

Comment: Yes, you can call `expect` from within `bash`. Can you explain why you want to do it that way?

Comment: @ArunPrakash, so, you'd like to include an `expect` script in a shell script to automate that same shell script? Why not just change the script to behave automatically without external help?

Comment: This feels like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) -- what are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: @RalfFriedl @ilkkachu @glenn The shell script that i wrote need inputs to proceed after a point. So I thought I would use `expect` for it. But I could not write it in a single `shell script`. When I use `expect` in the `shell script` , it halts for the input to be given. So had to write two scripts - one for expect and another shell script for which the input is to be given.

Comment: @ArunPrakash, yes, and especially if you wrote the yourself, why not modify it to accept the inputs in some other form, in some way that would lend itself more to being automated, _without requiring the use of `expect`_?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need your script to be interactive, then change `read var` to `var="fixed value"`.

Or, you can automate the input by passing values to your scripts standard input:

```
./myscript.sh <<END_OF_INPUTS
input string 1
input string 2
... and so on
END_OF_INPUTS
```

Or, you can put the values into the script itself:

```
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/sh
read -p "this one is interactive: " first

exec 0<<END_INPUT
foo
bar
END_INPUT
read -p "2nd input is automated: " second
read -p "3nd input is automated: " third

echo "1st input: $first"
echo "2nd input: $second"
echo "3rd input: $third"
echo done


$ sh test.sh
this one is interactive: I type this
1st input: I type this
2nd input: foo
3rd input: bar
done
```

Expect is a very useful tool, but there are not very many places where it's really essential.

Comment: First one ends up in a infinite loop. Second one throws a error `warning: here-document at line 61 delimited by end-of-file (wanted 'END_INPUT')` & `syntax error: unexpected end of file` even after ending END_INPUT

Comment: I suspect you made a typo: my code as posted is correct. Did you put whitespace before or after the `end_input` ending word?

Comment: No I didn't give spaces, I just copied your code

Comment: so where does "line 61" come from?

Comment: The mistake is form my end. I gave wrong input.

Answer (score 0):

You can start `expect` from a shell script, but `expect` can't control the input of a shell that isn't a child process of `expect`.

On the other hand, there is rarely a reason to use `expect` on the shell itself, whatever you ant to do with `expect` you can do directly from the shell. Most likely you don't want to use `expect` on the shell itself, but on commands started from the shell. So you can call `expect` from the shell and have `expect` call the programs that you want to control with `expect`.

Comment: I get it - `but expect can't control the input of a shell that isn't a child process of expect`

Comment: Why would you need `expect` on the shell itself?

Comment: The Shell script required some input to be given. So I thought I would automate with `expect`

Comment: There is rarely a reason why the shell script would want some import and not a program called by the shell script.